# Trigger github actions workflow when the repo topics change

Tags: github-actions

We are writing an action that fails PRs to master when we add the topic "lock-master" to a the repository.

The repo topics api is explained here:
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#replace-all-repository-topics

Is it possible to listen to any changes in the repo topics, and retrigger the workflow?

Comment: Why not creating a GHA workflow that would run on every PR and check through the Get all repository topics service (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-all-repository-topics) if the `lock-master` topic exists on the repo? Then if it exists, the workflow fails the PR?

Comment: @GuiFalourd That's what I did, but imagine the following scenario: 1. User A created a PR X that passed all tests 2. User B added the lock-master topic, that will fail future PRs but not PR X that already passed 3. User A merges PR X.

Comment: In that case, you would like the third step to re-trigger the workflow and fail the PR?

Comment: @GuiFalourd yes, I would like that changing the repository's topics will retrigger the workflow of all open PRs.